# Multiple consumers exactly-once processing with Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am looking to process elements on a queue (Kafka or Amazon Kinesis) and to have multiple operations to be performed on each element, for example:

- Write that to HDFS cluster
- Invoke a rest API
- Trigger a notification on slack.

On each of these operations I am expecting an exactly-once semantic, is this achievable in Apache Spark and how?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manage unique keys manually: but given that approach it *is* possible when using

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream
```

From the Spark docs http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html :

**Approach 2: Direct Approach (No Receivers)**

> each record is received by Spark Streaming
>   effectively exactly once despite failures.

And here is the `idempotency` requirement - so e.g. saving unique key per message in `Postgres`:

> In order to achieve
>   exactly-once semantics for output of your results, your output
>   operation that saves the data to an external data store must be either
>   idempotent, or an atomic transaction that saves results and offsets
>   (see Semantics of output operations in the main programming guide for
>   further information).

Here is an idea of the kind of code you would need to manage the unique keys (from http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/exactly-once-spark-streaming-from-apache-kafka/ ):

```
 stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    rdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
    // make sure connection pool is set up on the executor before writing
    SetupJdbc(jdbcDriver, jdbcUrl, jdbcUser, jdbcPassword)

    iter.foreach { case (key, msg) =>
      DB.autoCommit { implicit session =>
        // the unique key for idempotency is just the text of the message itself, for example purposes
        sql"insert into idem_data(msg) values (${msg})".update.apply
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A unique per-message ID would need to be managed.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly once is a side effect of at least once processing semantic, when the operations are idempotent. In your case, if all 3 operations are idempotent, then you can get exactly once semantic. The other way to get exactly once semantic is to wrap all the 3 operations and Kafka offset storage in one transaction, which is not feasible.

https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2016/05/18/exactly-once-stream-processing-semantics-not-exactly/